# Bullets vs. Numbering: which to use when?

Tags: style, technical-writing, formatting, academic-writing

A writer can either choose to use bullets or else stick to conventional (or in certain cases non-conventional) numbering. Are there set guidelines about when to use what? Is the use of numbering preferred over bullets in more professional settings (example, academic writing, technical reports, theses, etc.) or is it left to the choice of the writer?

Comment: They are called an "ordered" and an "unordered" list. You use the ordered list, if there is some order to the items. If the order of the items is irrelevant, you use the unordered list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In everyday writing, (say on the web, or an email) I'd use bullets where possible. I think they're more accessible and quicker to scan. Unless there were some reason to actually number things. The [Wikipedia style manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style#Bulleted_and_numbered_lists) spells this out well:

> Use numbers rather than bullets only if:
>
> - A need to refer to the elements by number may arise;
> - The sequence of the items is critical; or
> - The numbering has some independent meaning, for example in a listing of musical tracks.

In academic or tech writing, the governing style sheets or style guides (MLA, APA, etc.) should always be consulted. I'll leave it to our resident tech writers to provide more detail, but I'd consult those resources and only then use the logic above: Use my own preference for bullet points unless there's a reason not to.

It's worth noting that style guides all have specific requirements for how lists are used and formatted. APA at least seems to boil down to similar but more detailed advice as the wikipedia style guide; i.e., have a good reason for using the format you employ.

- APA on [numbered lists](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/02/lists-part-4-numbered-lists.html), [bulleted lists](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/lists-part-5-bulleted-lists.html)
- MLA on [seriation](http://www.docstyles.com/mlacrib.htm#Sec22) (conventional lists and in-paragraph lists) (Note that [MLA style seems to prohibit use of bulleted lists](http://www.ehow.com/how_7675414_use-bullets-lists-research-paper.html).)

Comment: I agree with this answer.  Specifically, when order matters, such as the sequence of steps in a procedure (do this, then do that, etc), *always* use numbering unless you have a style guide that tells you otherwise (and if you do, I'm curious whose it is as that would be unusual).

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I *think* that MLA prohibits bulleted lists, but I don't own a copy to check that. Chicago seems to prefer numbered lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a technical document, then you should follow whatever convention is required by the journal or publisher.

In everyday writing (i.e. email) I prefer to enumerate.  The point of email is to communicate efficiently.  If you expect an audience to respond, by enumerating, you are telling your audience reply with enumeration mapping to your original points.

E.g. your email might say :

> Below are my points :
>
> 1. The sky is blue.
> 2. Red is my favorite color

Response from reader might be :

> Responses :
>
> 1. In the day, the sky is blue. At night it is black.
> 2. My favorite color is pink.

This avoids people responding inline, which becomes a mess to read in a lengthy email chain. Bullet points don't work because no one is going to say 'bullet point 1', instead they'll give you a 'wall of text' response or respond inline.